# i have a dynamic tablayout but every time i push back button and re-enter my app again , my tab doubles , why?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

in my `TabLayout` i create my login `TabItem` dynamically at the `onCreate()` method of my `MainActivity` , but every time i exit from my application with `back` button and i re-enter my app , it creates that login `TabItem` again and so it doubles it every time , i tried to check and use :

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
   // create the first tab
}
```

but it didn't work , can you please help me ?
here is my code for the `MainActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> fragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.myTabLayout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Adapter.createTab(new LoginFragment(), "Login", getSupportFragmentManager(), viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the code for `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) { super(manager);}

    public void createTab(Fragment fragment, String title, FragmentManager manager, ViewPager viewPager) {
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(manager);
        MainActivity.fragments.add(fragment);
        MainActivity.fragmentsTitle.add(title);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MainActivity.fragments.get(position);
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return MainActivity.fragmentsTitle.get(position);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing static keyword from your list in MainActivity. Instead use final to prevent reinitialisation of list.

Comment: @mnp343 i can not make them final , i am creating and removing tabitems ( fragments ) in them all the time .

Comment: there must be a professional way , why on earth is it creating that login tab every time ? i prevent the app from creating for example `Register` tab just by checking if its already there or not like `if(fragmentsTitle.contains("Register")` , but it is not working with `Login` Tab , wich is the first tab , if i do this method for `Login` tab , i would get back to the program with a blank page !! and i don't know why ??

Comment: that's ok you remove tabs. Even after making them final you can do that. You are redefining values inside locations of array, and not the array reference itself.

Comment: It's creating that tab everytime because static things stay alive as long as they get killed. And the professional way on earth to create tab and store them inside list is to keep that list inside viewpager adaptor.

Comment: Separate things from the place where you really don't need or use them, isolate them from those places.

Comment: i actually tried what you mentioned at your first comment, and it works, the `Login TabItem` doesn't get duplicated anymore, that's good . and as you said in your last comment, yes. that's right, i tried to separate all the codes and functions and put them in another class, so the `MainActivity` doesn't get so overpopulated. i have to rewrite some of my codes .

Comment: thanks for your help , write it as an answer so i can rate it as correct answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing static keyword from your list in MainActivity. Instead use final to prevent reinitialisation of list.
It's creating that tab everytime because static things stay alive as long as they get killed. And the professional way on earth to create tab and store them inside list is to keep that list inside viewpager adaptor.
I am happy it was helpful.